# How to make string f-string after variable initiazation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, formatting, format

Let's suppose I get some string and set it to variable - it can't be created as f-string:

```
str1 = 'date time for {val1} and {val2}'
```

Then variables inside the string initialized:

```
val1 = 1
val2 = 77
```

Calling `print(str1)` will return `'date time for {val1} and {val2}'`. But I would like to get
`'date time for 1 and 77'`

Is there any function to make a string as a F string? So I want to call something `make_F(str1)` and get f-string

PS I cant use dict `{'val1':1, 'val2':77}` with `.format` because don't know which variables will be needed in  the string. I just want magic happen with F-string.

Comment: OP made a mistake and didn't assign `val2` in the sample code

Comment: @CDJB thank you, been searching for a while

Comment: [How do I convert a string into an f-string?](//stackoverflow.com/q/47339121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need:

```
str1 = 'date time for {val1} and {val2}'

val1 = 1
val2 = 77

print(eval(f"f'{str1}'"))
```

Comment: Two warnings if you're using this. Firstly, make sure str1 comes from a trusted source, since eval will execute any Python commands contained in it. Secondly, str1 should not be a multi-line string - if it is, then use eval(f'f"""{str1}"""') otherwise eval will throw an EOL error.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to describe variables as e.g

```
var1 = None
var2 = None
```

Then you can use it with f-string like this:

```
x = f'print {var1} and {var2}'

print(x)
```

And thats it, you will get the result.